# Close button style in Chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to change the back button icon in chrome custom tabs from the standard '**x**' to a back arrow, '**<**'.

I know I can use the `setCloseButtonIcon(Bitmap icon)` method while I'm building the intent to set a custom bitmap for the button.

But checking this issue: [Close button should be shown instead of a back button on the toolbar of chrome custom tab](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495145), from the Chromium bug tracker I saw that it was fixed with this resolution:

> The flag "android.support.CUSTOM_TABS:close_button_style" was added
>   for the developers to customize the style of close button. The default
>   setting is "X", and developers are granted with an option of "<".

The problem is that I can't find a way to use it while I'm building the custom tab. 
Does anyone know how I can change the style using this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CLOSE_BUTTON_STYLE` was an old parameter and it was removed in this [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/75e3fda0d374a97922177d55803dbe36962d364e):

> Let client app customize close button
>
> There has been strong feedback requesting customizeable close button.
>   This CL implements it by getting a bitmap from the passed intent.
>
> BUG=513512
>
> Review URL: https://codereview.chromium.org/1263583003
>
> Cr-Commit-Position: refs/heads/master@{#340941}

As you can see it was [removed](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/75e3fda0d374a97922177d55803dbe36962d364e%5E%21/#F7) from `CustomTabIntentDataProvider.java`.

Now the only available option is to use the method `setCloseButtonIcon(Bitmap icon)` that you already know.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your answer. I should have looked trough the issues a bit more.